# When is the user charged for an in-app purchase?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

When is the user **charged** for an iOS in-app purchase?

Is it between [addPayment](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPaymentQueue/addPayment:) and [paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransactionObserver_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SKPaymentTransactionObserver/paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:) receives `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased`, or is it after calling [finishTransaction](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPaymentQueue/finishTransaction:)? Or somewhere else?

Is this explicitly mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: Did you get more info since October ? I'm having the same concerns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for this.

> SKPaymentTransaction
>   A transaction is created for every payment added to the queue. Each transaction has properties that allow your application to determine the status of the transaction. **When payment is collected**, the transaction includes additional details about the successful transaction.

Which is here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/MakingaPurchase/MakingaPurchase.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH3-SW1

It looks like when you have a `transactionReceipt` then the payment is completed.

Answer (score 0):

It’s as you describe -- The user is charged in between addPayment and when paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: receives SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased.

But the exact timing of when the user is charged during that phase is not deterministic as it happens by the StoreKit framework.

In the headers, there is a comment next to SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased that reads "user has been charged.” So once you receive SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased you know the user has been charged.

Comment: So even if I never call finish transaction, the user will be charged ? I don't understand why Apple insist so much on : "deliver your content before launching finishTransaction" though

Comment: @CedricSoubrie Finish transaction is there to let apple know that your app has responded to the purchase. If you finished the transaction before content was delivered, and your app restarted (before or during the content download) then apple wouldn't know to re-send the updatedTransaction message.